# amCharts rendering is slow in IE11

Tags: angularjs, amcharts

I have created the charts(Line/Bar) using amChart library. I am injecting the data which is more than 50 objects. In chrome charts are rendering fast but in case of IE 11/Edge, amCharts is rendering in 5-8s. I have tested with demo https://www.amcharts.com/demos/simple-column-chart/ where I have added more object to test in IE and Chrome. In IE 11 charts rendering is very slow. Even I test the changes after setting "startDuration": 0.

Can someone help me on this.

Comment: Please provide a fiddle with your actual test case that reproduces the issue. IE tends to be slower but not *that* much slower.

Comment: Have you tried angular-chat? http://jtblin.github.io/angular-chart.js/ I'm using it in a lot of projects and works fine in IE11